# ABS ActionBar with custom view not working

Tags: actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar, custom-view

I wanted to create ActionBar with icons in center and I made it with `getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.abs_layout);`. But there problems with events. when I click to `ImageView` `onOptionsItemSelected` not working.

Where is my mistake? Can I do this other ways?

there is my code:[code_files](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6li7e51ge3wvmee/-c_Zi6P7SD)

How can I add `OnClickListener` to the `ImageView`s